# how to merge recursive array with replace value

Tags: php

[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DN3Q.png)

I want result array looklike this 
 please help I stuck at this array for a while please

```
foreach($x as $key => $value){
    foreach ($y[$key] as $key2 => $value2){

        if($x[$key] == $y[$key][$key2]){
            $z[$key][$key2] = $value2;
        }else{
            $z[$key][$key2] = $value1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include an example of the specific values in the array, the code you're using, and the output that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize that there was an image. From the image I can't be entirely sure if there is any pattern to the keys for the arrays A and B. From the looks of it, it looks like they generally share the same structure. You might need to add a few more checks but hopefully the sample code before will help.

```
<?php

    $A = array(
        // ...
        "18" => array (
            "2020-01-01" => null,
            "2020-01-02" => "leave",
            "2020-01-03" => "leave",
            "2020-01-04" => "leave",
            "2020-01-05" => null,
            "2020-01-06" => null,
            "2020-01-07" => null,
            "2020-01-08" => "leave",
            "2020-01-09" => "leave",
            "2020-01-10" => null
        )
        // ...
    );

    $B = array(
        // ...
        "18" => array (
            "2020-01-01" => null,
            "2020-01-02" => null,
            "2020-01-03" => "16:14:19",
            "2020-01-04" => null,
            "2020-01-05" => "16:39:20",
            "2020-01-06" => "10:14:19",
            "2020-01-07" => null,
            "2020-01-08" => null,
            "2020-01-09" => "14:10:03",
            "2020-01-10" => "09:57:31"
        )
        // ...
    );

    $indices = array_keys($A);

    // Loop over the full array
    foreach($indices as $index) {

        // each index will be 17, 18, 19, ect

        // Then loop through each key in the sub array
        foreach($A[$index] as $key => $value) {

            // If null or empty string continue
            if(!$value || strlen($value) === 0) {
                continue;
            }

            // Otherwise overwrite value of B
            $B[$index][$key] = $value;
        }

    }

    print_r($B);


?>
```

Basically you loop over array A, and if there is a value for a given index and key, then you overwrite B for that given index and key, otherwise you just continue. The program gives the result.

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [2020-01-01] => 
            [2020-01-02] => leave
            [2020-01-03] => leave
            [2020-01-04] => leave
            [2020-01-05] => 16:39:20
            [2020-01-06] => 10:14:19
            [2020-01-07] => 
            [2020-01-08] => leave
            [2020-01-09] => leave
            [2020-01-10] => 09:57:31
        )

)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
loop through both the array 
array 1, array 2
foreach ($array2 as $value)
{
$array3 =$value;
if($value == ""){
$array3 =$value;
}
}
```

Comment: it currently not working because this was array currently have 2d dimension with no index

Comment: @PanudetPanumas panumas why you downvoted you should be specific with your question with clear code.

Comment: @jithin new users can't downvote. Your answer has bad formatting and is only a guess.

Comment: I did not downvoted this, but: 
the if clausule is useless, with your code $array3 will always be $value.
the if is not doing the comparison by type (and not even checking if $value is actually defined). 
the comment does not have the proper syntax.

So, yeah, I can see why this got downvoted, honestly